# Equivalent of Java meta-annotations in C#

Tags: java, c#, xunit

I would like to simplify some of the *Xunit* attributes to reduce some of the code and implement all of the tests as stereotypes. For instance, I'm making use of its `TraitAttribute` in my integration test code to differentiate the endpoint under test between numerous stubs in the same testing class.

```cs
[Fact]
[Trait("Action", "Create")]
public async Task CreateCategory_ReturnsNewCategoryIfParamsValid()
{
  // test case implementation       
}
```

In **most of the cases**, *Spring Framework* in Java allows me to rewrite annotations as [meta-annotations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Annotations/Meta-Annotations).

Is it possible to do the same thing in *C#* for attributes?

At the end, I would like to write my test stubs as following.

```cs
[Fact]
[ActionTrait(Actions.Create)]
public async Task CreateCategory_ReturnsNewCategoryIfParamsValid()
{
  // test case implementation       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to do the same thing in C# for attributes?

Yes, since a C# attribute is just a class that derived from `Attribute`, and classes can have attributes, that means that an attribute can itself have attributes.

It is entirely up to the code that reads and processes attributes to look for attributes-on-attributes.

Comment: Yes, you can create an attribute any time, but it's up to something to reflect over your type/function/etc and do something with the information. In this case, *XUnit* understands the `TraitAttribute`, but it won't understand your `MetaTraitAttribute`, so it won't buy you much. And, since attribute constructor parameters need to be const-ish, you can't create a function (or some other mechanism) that translates `Actions.Create` to the strings `"Action"` and `"Create"`.

Comment: @Flydog57 I already said that the code using the annotation will have to look for meta-annotations, which is no different from the Spring meta-annotations, which only works because *Spring* is actively looking for them. So to get [**xUnit.net**](https://xunit.net/) to process meta-annotations, you have to enhance xUnit.net to do so. Since xUnit.net is **open source**, you can do that.